# How to return structure with special criterias

Tags: java

I have this method that prepare data table for rendering with all visible columns:

```
private SearchResultDataCell[] prepareTable(Object[] result) {
    int rowIndex = 0;
    final SearchResultDataCell row[] = new SearchResultDataCell[COUNT];
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[0])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[1])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[2])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[3])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[4])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[5])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[6])));
    return row; 
}
```

Now I need to implement feature that will allow to render only special columns.
As I understand I should pass to the method some collection with visible indexes that should be rendered, so method signature should look like:

```
private SearchResultDataCell[] prepareTable(Object[] test, List<Integer> visibleIndexes)
```

But how actually I could return structure with visible columns? How should I rewrite this method to make code as more manageable?

Comment: Write that method using a loop. Any time you write a line of code and than think "I need to copy-paste it a few times and I'll be done" your mind should shout at you to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the code more manageable, you can do the following for starters:

```
private SearchResultDataCell[] prepareTable(Object[] result) {
    final SearchResultDataCell row[] = new SearchResultDataCell[COUNT];
    for(int index = 0; index < row.length; index++) {
        row[index] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[index])));
    }
    return row; 
}
```

Then you can use the suggestion provided in previous answer to manage your special criterias with the following modifications

```
private SearchResultDataCell[] prepareTable(Object[] test, ArrayList<Integer> visibleIndexes){
    SearchResultDataCell[] row = new SearchResultDataCell[visibleIndexes.size()];
    for(int index = 0 ; index < visibleIndexes.size(); index++){
        row[index] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(test[visibleIndexes.get(index)])));
    }
    return row;
}
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: `int rowIndex = 0` is not used.

Comment: I don't like constricting to ArrayList (even though I understand why) - I think that (admittedly somewhat uglier) solution with iterating over visibleIndexes and manually incrementing index would be preferable

Answer (score 2):

If I understand to thing what you need, you need to make something like this

```
private SearchResultDataCell[] prepareTable(Object[] result) {
    int rowIndex = 0;
    final SearchResultDataCell row[] = new SearchResultDataCell[COUNT];
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[0])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[1])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[2])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[3])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[4])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[5])));
        row[rowIndex++] = dataCell(notNull(String.valueOf(result[6])));
    return row; 
    }

    private SearchResultDataCell[] prepareTable(Object[] test, List<Integer> visibleIndexes){
        SearchResultDataCell[] tableToRet = new SearchResultDataCell[visibleIndexes.size()];
        for(int i= 0 ; i < visibleIndexes.size(); i++){
            tableToRet[i] = test[visibleIndexes.get(i)];
        }
        return tableToRet;
    }
```

Comment: Btw maybe you have to make there `List<int> visibleIndexes`

Comment: Just a nitpick - it'll be widely inefficient if `visibleIndexes` is any `List` implementation other than `ArrayList`

Comment: so it could be `visibleIndexes.get(i)` :) 
[doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Umm... Not really... I mean, it's the correct syntax, but it doesn't change the efficiency - that's just how lists work, getting an arbitrary element is O(n). O(1) is guaranteed only for getting the first element, and iterating with `next`

Comment: If you telling it, I have to trust you .. :-D